# Rendering another view in Parent after Child component callback

Tags: reactjs, components, use-state

I really don't know how I can do this, I have a login.tsx file and App.tsx file:

in login.tsx I have:

```
const Login = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

[...]

const handleLogin = () => {
    if (state.password === 'password' && state.username.length > 2) { 
      dispatch({
        type: 'loginSuccess',
        payload: 'Login Successfully'
      });
      // here I want to add the callback to the parent function App
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: 'loginFailed',
        payload: 'Username too short or incorrect password'
      });
    }
  };
```

and in App.tsx:

```
 if (true) { // replace true with the callback from the child
        return <Login  />
      }
  return ( // (else)
    <div className="App"> // the other view we want once logged in successfully
     [...]
```

So that once the user is logged in it automatically render another view. Sorry for the very stupid question I am not very experienced with React.

NB: I know this is not the secured way to do it (login auth should be with JWT/OAuth etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a state in your App.tsx that is responsible for keeping track of which component to render, e.g.: `const [showLogin, setShowLogin] = useState(true);`.
Then use the `showLogin` variable in your if/else statement.

You will also need to pass down a function as a prop to your Login component that will update `showLogin` once the logging in has completed, like so:
`<Login onLogin={() => setShowLogin(false)} />`.

Then, in your handleLogin function, call the onLogin function passed down to your Login component.

*edit from OP:*
Also slightly changed the code to `const Login = (props: {onLogin: any }) => {`
and call `props.onLogin();`